# java non-static to static method -- hiding or overriding

Tags: java, overriding, method-hiding

is re-defining a non-static method in a subclass with the same everything but as static overriding or hiding it ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html says hiding. but when i declare the superclass method as final, i get an override error.

superclass declaration is

```
final static void display() { ... }
```

subclass:

```
void display() { ... }
```

gives override error.

Comment: Both methods are non-static here, are you missing something?

Comment: thanks-- thats a typo. the one in superclass should be static

Comment: Making a static method final doesn't make sense, as you cannot override it.

Comment: it is. i couldn't get an answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is re-defining a non-static method in a subclass with the same everything but as static overriding or hiding it?

It's neither, because doing so triggers a [compilation error](http://ideone.com/hIfyfb), rendering your program invalid.

```
class A {
    void x();
}
class B extends A {
    // ERROR!!!
    static void x();
}
```

Hiding happens when both methods in the pair are static methods; overriding happens when both methods in the pair are instance methods. When one of the two is a static method and the other one is an instance method, Java considers it an error. It does not matter if the instance method is final or not; it also does not matter if the static method is in the base or in the derived class: Java calls it an error either way.

The compiler message that says "cannot override" is misleading, though: I think that "name collision" would have been a better name for such conditions, because "overriding" is reserved for situations with two *instance* methods.

Comment: read definitions of hiding and overriding, read what i`ve been asking above.

Comment: @ashley I know the difference between hiding and overriding, and I think I completely understood what you are asking about. I expanded on my thought a little in the paragraph that I added at the end of my answer.

Comment: that should do it. so it is a matter of static-to-dynamic before getting into hiding/overriding/not "zone". 


in that case, "final" still says the last word on overriding: iff it is only the existance of the final keyword not allowing what you are trying to do, then youre overriding. 


the compiler messages on this are totally misleading. it keeps saying  "cannot override" whenever i redefine an instance method as a static one in the sub or vice versa. 


thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ashley I agree with you completely on the compiler's message being misleading: it should not call it "overriding" or "hiding". It should say "cannot override" only when the other method is marked `final`, not when the other method is `static`.

Answer (score 4):

The method you describe is an instance method, not a static method.  You cannot hide instance methods, only static methods.  An instance method declared `final` cannot be overridden in a subclass, and this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, then that link i posted saying that is saying it wrong.

it is not allowing me to re-define the other way round either-- a static method of the superclass as non-static in the sub.

Comment: @ashley No it's not. That document refers to hiding in two contexts: fields, and static methods.  It never says that you can hide *instance* methods.  And no, you can't change the static-ness of a method in a subclass.

Comment: read again in the bullet-list: "You can write a new static method in the subclass that has the same signature as the one in the superclass, thus hiding it."

Comment: @ashley Yes, "the one" there refers to the static method in the superclass.  It's clear from the context that this is the intended meaning.  Your example code uses instance methods, not static methods; this is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`final static void display() { ... }`

The above method is having **non-access modifier** `final`, and a method which has been made `final` **can't be overridden.**

Answer (score 0):

How can you override a method that is final.

The final methods can never be overrided in the subclass.

That is the compilation error..

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a final method...

Ex:

```
class Super
{
  final void display()
  {
    //do something
  }

  void show()
  {
    //Do Something
  }
}


class Sub extends Super
{
  //Not Valid hence Compile Error
  void display()
  {
    //do something
  }

  //Valid
  void show()
  {
    //Do Something
  }
}
```

Comment: you can hide a final method-- thats the distinction between hiding and overriding. read my Q above.

Comment: Yes !! Whan you override Static method of Superclass into Subclass. The Superclass implementation gets hide.

Comment: check that with your compiler.

Comment: A method can be declared final to prevent subclasses from overriding or hiding it