# When is method hiding practically used?

Tags: java

i want to know the practical use of the Method Hiding in java.

For ex.

```
class MyClass{
     public static void myMethod(){
         //some code here
     }
}

class MyClass1 extends MyClass{

     public static void myMethod(){
         //some code here
     }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    MyClass1 obj1=new MyClass1();
    MyClass obj=obj1;
    MyClass.myMethod();  // this method will run the parent Class method myMethod then what is the use of this practically.                           
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `@overriding` annotation?  If that's a typo and should be `@Override`, why is it put on a static method?  It won't compile.

Comment: Method hiding is useless IMHO. It only cause confusion.

Answer (score 5):

First, this is not a form of overriding.  (Overriding occurs when methods are inherited, and `static` methods are NOT inherited in Java.)

This is called "hiding" ... but is a bit of an illusion.  It is trivially easy to access a hidden static method or field.  As a result this "technique" is not particularly useful.

If anything, hiding is a bad idea because it *can be* a source of program errors ... or at least, of source of code that looks like it does one this but is actually doing something different.

So my advice is to avoid hiding rather than look for places to use it.  (With hindsight, it might have been better if the Java language treated it as a compilation error ...)

---

For the record, here's an example of hiding:

```
public class A {
    public static String method() { return "'A.method()'"; }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static String method() { return "'B.method()'"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.method());  // prints 'A.method()'
        System.out.println(B.method());  // prints 'B.method()'
        System.out.println(method());    // prints 'B.method()'
    }
}
```

In the above, the version of `method()` in `B` hides the version in `A`, but you can call it anyway.  The "hiding" is an illusion.

And here's an example that shows the kind of problems that it can cause:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

System.out.println(a.method());  // prints 'A.method()'
System.out.println(b.method());  // prints 'B.method()'

b = a;
System.out.println(b.method());  // prints 'B.method()'
```

It *looks* like we are calling instance methods ... until you hit the 3rd `method()` call.

---

There are two other terms - "shadowing" and "obscuring" - which apply in different contexts:

- Shadowing is where name in an inner scope redeclares a name in an outer scope.
- Obscuring is where you have the name is used for a member, an type and/or a package.  This one you really want to avoid, because it leads to really confusing code.  But fortunately you have to flout Java's identifier style rules to get burnt by this.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html it is called "hiding". "If a subclass defines a class method with the same signature as a class method in the superclass, the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass". Apart from that great answer for actually answering what the OP asks.

Comment: The JLS also mentions "method hiding" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html, unless I'm missing something

Comment: man @Stephen C i say i want practical use of that otherwise i also know what is going to do

Comment: @Sahil - There are no good examples ... only poor / dangerous ones.  That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific use for "method hiding" as you call it.  Rather, it is a consequence of using the same static method signature in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

When you have static method in the super class and if you create a method with same signature in the sub class, the super class method will get called if you are using the super class reference and sub class method gets called if you are using the sub class reference. The call to the static method is resolved at compile time itself . Hence `MyClass.myMethod()` will invoke the parent class method , while `MyClass1.myMethod()` invokes the sub class method.

As per the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> If a subclass defines a class method with the same signature as a class method in the superclass, the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass.

Comment: The OP was asking what the "practical use" of it is (i.e. why would you do it?)

Answer (score 0):

Java won't resolve method call at runtime and depending upon type of Object which is used to call static method, corresponding method will be called.

It means if you use Parent class's type to call static method, original static will be called from patent class, on ther other hand if you use Child class's type to call static method, method from child class will be called. **In short you can not override static method in Java**.

And worth reading :[java non-static to static method -- hiding or overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447878/java-non-static-to-static-method-hiding-or-overriding)

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand that why you create object of your class because they are not importand here and don't play any role in your question .

i wan to clear it for you with an example . consider that `MyClass` as `Car` class and consider `MyClass2` as `bus` class (consider you are programming for a car company!!) and also consider that `public static void myMethod()` as `NumberOfProduced` now if you want to understand the number of car that the company produced you should use `Car.NumberOfProduced()` (also with additional code in it .) but if you want to understand the number of bus production you use `Bus.NumberOfProduced()`. and i again mention that object don't have any effect on the result (except if you want to count number of created object.)
i hope it be useful for you .

Comment: This doesn't even mention the situation where you would get hiding.